# How do I send an Enterprise Activation email? Using EnableBlackBerryUserDispatcherAttributes?

Tags: web-services, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

This is regarding a Blackberry that is connected to a BES Server, and the Administration Web Service.

I need to enable and send an Enterprise Activation email, however I need to also set an ActivationPassword.

I looked at the help document and after tracing the abstract classes, I think I need to do "something" with `EnableBlackBerryUserDispatcherAttributes`.

How do I send an enterprise activation email with a password to an Exchange user?  I can't find anything, anywhere.  (Sure I can add a user to the server, but what good is that if I can't activate the account !?)

I've found the following objects in the webservice that indicate it is possible, but I can't figure out how to use them...

- ActivationPassword;
- ActivationContext;
- ActivationPasswordType;
- ActivationPasswordOperationTypeEnumType;
- clearActivationPassword;
- EnterpriseActivationEvent;
- setActivationPassword;

Just to be clear the online samples only address the creation of a user, not enabling them.

My alternative is to [shell out](https://www.blackberry.com/IncidentBasedSupport/?INC=INC000022273709) $250 bucks for this missing documentation.

If you are an ISV partner or T3 subscriber, the answer to this question is free for you at devsupport@rim.com so I'll appreciate any strings you can pull as well.  While you're at it I'd appreciate if you can tell me how to update the email component as described on this part of the admin website

> The user list from the company
>   directory is automatically updated on
>   a timely basis. The update process can
>   be manually started using the email
>   component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have a look at the dispatcher webservice. This means you have to generate a stub for the dispatcher webservice as shown in the tutorial. The stub is a instance of com.rim.bes.bas.baa.BAADispatcher which holds methods for setting and generating EA-passwords.

Regards